# UINavigationController from Storyboard coming as nil

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, null

I'm coming from being accustomed to using XIBs to Storyboards now.

I'm trying to instantiate a UINavigationController from my storyboard as follows (in awakeFromNib):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];

UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                               instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"PassengerNavigation"];
```

my instance, however, is coming up as nil, I have checked & double checked that the Identifier is correct (and the name of the storyboard as well) but it's still not working

My mainStoryboard is also showing as nil

But if I pass an empty Identifier to controller then it crashes complaining that the storyboard does not have a controller with such ID

what am i doing wrong>?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you using awakeFromNib if you're using storyboards?

Comment: just switched to viewDidLoad and it's still the same. extremelly new to storyboards I admit, which is the best place for this?

Comment: I'll rephrase, why do you need to instantiate a view controller while another one is loading? What exactly do you need to have done?